# Weighted interpolation in pandas.Series

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Let's consider a series of values:

```
s = pandas.Series([0, np.nan, np.nan, 1])
```

and a series of weigths:

```
w = pandas.Series([np.nan, 1, 0, 1])
```

A classic linear interpolation would give me:

```
>>> s.interpolate()
0    0.000000
1    0.333333
2    0.666667
3    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

I need a weighted_interpolate method which consider that `w[i] ~ s[i] - s[-1]` and should return:

```
>>> weighted_interpolate(s, w)
0    0.000000
1    0.500000
2    0.500000
3    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

How can I achieve this? I found the `piecewise_polynomial` method but I didn't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: I'm going to be doing weighted interpolation soon! I was hoping I would find something in SciPy. If not, I will have to do it manually...

Comment: This looks like something you might do with cumulative sums `w.cumsum()` might give you something you can just multiply by the range you're trying to interpolate.

Comment: Given that your first weight is `NaN` and your next two points in `s` are also `NaNs`, it appears to me that 100% of the weight would be applied in your last point, i.e. `NaN, NaN, NaN, 1`.

Comment: First weight is "useless" in my case since it's proportional to the derivative in `i` computed as `s[i] - s[i-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael gives me the hint i needed. Here's an example of weighted interpolate with only ufuncs (eg numpy functions).

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
s = pd.Series([0, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2])
w = pd.Series([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1])
print(s.interpolate())
sb = s.fillna(method='ffill')
se = s.fillna(method='bfill')
cw = w.cumsum()
w2 = pd.Series(None, index=s.index)
w2[~np.isnan(s)] = cw[~np.isnan(s)]
wb = w2.fillna(method='ffill')
we = w2.fillna(method='bfill')
cw = (cw - wb) / (we - wb)
r = sb + cw * (se - sb)
r.update(s)
print(r)
```

Below a plot of the known points, the linear interpolate and the weighted interpolation

[image: Example]